# Photo library won't import back on Mojave after Catalina

Tags: mojave, photos, catalina

I have downgraded to Mojave after the automatic installation of Catalina that have given me a lot of problems.
Now I have a Photo library that won't open back on mojave.
It's a 178GB library and I need it back.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You had Catalina running and then downgraded to Mojave?   What do you mean that your photo library "won't open back on mojave"?  Was it backed-up somewhere (hard drive, iCloud, etc)?  What have you already tried to get it back?

Comment: yes I had a backup in time machine but it doesn't work either... I mean that the Photo library has been corrupted by the new Photo app under Catalina

Comment: Did the photo library work under catalina? Can you just use someone else's computer and like a large hard drive?

Comment: Just to confirm, you didn't have all your photos in iCloud or another cloud service?

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you a work around.

1. Go to you Pictures folder
2. Right click your Photos library, "Show Package Contents"
3. All photos are in the "Masters" folder. Create a new Photo library and import.

At 178GB I'm guessing you have some level of organization, folders, etc. I'm unsure if that's recoverable.

Comment: @DaFois were you ever able to determine whether the organization of photos by date is recoverable? I'm thinking of downgrading from Catalina to Mojave but wanted to make sure about this first.

Answer (score 0):

The database underlying the Photos library is different in Catalina and Mojave (and again in Big Sur). To convert a Catalina library into Mojave, open it on a Mac running Catalina, enable iCloud photos and upload all the photos to iCloud. Then sign into this iCloud account on a Mac running Mojave, enable iCloud photos and sync. Since you have a rather large library, you'll need to subscribe to a suitable iCloud plan, the minimum duration is 1 month.

To just extract the photos from the Catalina library, the options are:

- Get the original photos (without edits) from the Masters folder
  of your Catalina Photos library, then import into a new Mojave Photos library.
- Export photos along with edits and metadata as explained
  [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/photos/pht6e157c5f/mac), but they'll all go into one big folder without organization.
- Use a third party app such as [Photos Takeout](https://www.photostakeout.com) to export photos in year-wise folders. You can include or exclude metadata, edits etc., and preserve arrangement of photos in albums. As you have a Catalina Photos library, the app must be installed on a Mac running Catalina (It won't read a Catalina library on a Mojave Mac). Then import the folders into Photos on your Mac running Mojave.